# set breakpoints to trigger after execution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

I'm using visual studio 2012. The problem is when I use breakpoints to debug my code and set specific lines to break on, the breakpoint breaks on the line, but before the line is executed. I need the line to get executed and then break on the line (post execution), so I can see the values assigned, otherwise now I have to add extra line after every breakpoint and break on that line. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the breakpoint and when VS is there just press F11 :D

Comment: F11 will step into the function or sub while F10 will go to the next line of code (executing the function or sub). And i hopee i make sense....

Comment: Yes you can use F11 or F10

Answer (score 2):

Add the break point to the line you are currently breaking and when the execution breaks on that unexecuted line, hit F10. It will execute that line and will still be on break.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I also use F10 and F11 but when I do this debugging routine several times I just put a semicolumn on the next line and put breakpoint on it. That way the expression before is evaluated and you see all necessary values.

The semicolumn(`;`) is empty expression. Something like `pass` in python.